# cant paginate with containable

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

In `cakephp` I can't get paginate to work with containable.

I followed the docs and I can't get it to work with just 2 tables. Instead I get every associated table.

I get this error as well:

`Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property StudentsController::$paginate has no effect`

The code works fine with a find all.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable

```
 $this->Student->Behaviors->load('Containable');

            $this->paginate['Student'] = array(

               'conditions' => array( 'student_inactive' => false,'Student.student_enq' => true  ),
                'limit'=>10,
                 'fields' => array('Student.id,last_name,first_name')   ,
               'contain' => array('Guardian' => array( 
                                        'fields' => array('id', 'guardian_email', 'guardian_first_name', 'guardian_last_name'  ))) ,

            'order' => 'Student.id'
                );

            $st = $this->paginate('Student');


array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'id' => '233',
            'student_inactive' => false,
            'student_enq' => false,
            'student_unallocated' => false,
            'first_name' => 'Aadil',
.....
        ),
        'TutoringType' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'value' => 'Individual Tuition'
        ),
        'Referral' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => 'Google - Organic',
            'details' => ''
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(

            'conditions' => array( 'student_inactive' => false,'Student.student_enq' => true  ),
            'limit'=>10,
            'fields' => array('Student.id,last_name,first_name')   ,
            'contain' => array('Guardian' => array( 
                                    'fields' => array('id', 'guardian_email', 'guardian_first_name', 'guardian_last_name'  ))) ,

            'order' => 'Student.id'
            );

        $st = $this->Paginator->paginate('Student');
```

Comment: I added public $components = array('Paginator');             but I still get this error   Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property StudentsController::$paginate has no effect